# Getting error TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable - Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to load the update password feature. When I try to pass the username parameter from the forgot-password.html page to the change-password.html page, I get an error TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable.

**note: i use mysql for the database**

here is my **forget-password.html** code:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('reset_password') }}" method="POST" class="needs-validation">
.....
</form>
```

here is my **python code** for **forget-password.html** page:

```
# FORGET PASSWORD
@app.route('/forget-password/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forget_password():
  if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form:
    username = request.form['username']    
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s', (username,))
    account = cursor.fetchone()
    if account:
        return redirect(url_for('reset_password'), username=username)
    else:
      flash('Username not registered!', 'danger')
  elif request.method == 'POST':
      flash('Please fill all form!', 'danger')
  return render_template('form/forget-password.html')
```

here is the code for the **reset-password.html** page:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('reset_password') }}" method="POST" class="needs-validation">
....
</form>
```

this is the **python** code for **reset-password.html** page:

```
# RESET PASSWORD
@app.route('/reset-password/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password():

  # GET DATA USERNAME
  username = request.args.get['username']

  if request.method == 'POST' and 'password1' in request.form and 'password2' in request.form:
    
    password1 = request.form['password1']
    password2 = request.form['password2']    

    if password1 == password2:
      # HASH Password
      hashPass = sha256_crypt.encrypt(password1)

      # UPDATE PASSWORD
      cursor.execute('UPDATE accounts SET password=%s WHERE username=%s', (hashPass, username))
      mysql.connection.commit()

      # REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE
      flash("Password berhasil diubah!", "success")
      return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
    # IF PASSWORD NOT MATCH
      flash('Password not match!', 'danger')
  # elif request.method == 'POST':
  #   # JIKA BELUM TERDAFTAR
  #     flash('Please fill all form!', 'danger')
  return render_template('form/reset-password.html')
```

Comment: `username = request.args.get['username']` get is a function, not a list.  Use `()`, not `[]`.

Comment: you need `request.args.get('username')` with `()` or `request.args['username']` without `get`

Comment: thanks, this worked when I changed username = request.args.get['username'] to username = request.args.get('username').

Comment: but I don't get the user name data from the previous form. Was there an error when I sent it?